# ViewController in Xcode Playground - frame reporting double sized (viewDidLoad)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift-playground, viewdidload

I am using a `UIViewController` subclass in an Xcode Swift playground. The view of the controller is apparently reporting as double-sized. Am I doing something wrong or did I stumble into a bug?

When I place a yellow subview of half the width into the view, it's covering the entire width.

Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class ViewController : UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    title = "Double Frame"
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.frame // inspecting the frame size: 768 x 1024

    let halfV = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200,
                                     width: Int(view.frame.width / 2),
                                     height: Int(view.frame.width / 2)))
    halfV.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view.addSubview(halfV)

  }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
```

[image]

Comment: Your view controller's view is getting resized sometime after `viewDidLoad` is called.  You need to size your yellow with constraints/autoresizing masks/some other method that will resize it when it's superview resizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You view controller's view is going to be sized using auto layout. The auto layout pass is going to occur after `viewDidLoad`. If you want to programmatic size your subview by referencing the `frame` of your view controller's view, you should move that code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. For example:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    let halfV = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        title = "Double Frame"
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.frame // inspecting the frame size: 768 x 1024


        halfV.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        view.addSubview(halfV)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        halfV.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200,
               width: CGFloat(view.frame.width / 2),
               height: CGFloat(view.frame.width / 2))
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
```